# newrelic creates huge log files on server

Tags: logging, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I faced with server disk overflow in couple days. Before it was full by 10%. The reason is files `newrelic_agent.log` files with size 5 - 30 giga bytes. I found such big files in `nginx` folder `site-enabled` and in home directories of `node.js express` applications.

```
{"name":"newrelic","hostname":"hostname","pid":355,"component":"redis","level":10,"msg":"Adding Redis command trace segment transaction 2769.","time":"2014-01-02T06:20:11.894Z","v":0}
{"name":"newrelic","hostname":"hostname","pid":355,"component":"redis","level":10,"msg":"Adding Redis command trace segment transaction 2769.","time":"2014-01-02T06:20:11.894Z","v":0}
{"name":"newrelic","hostname":"hostname","pid":355,"component":"redis","level":10,"msg":"Adding Redis command trace segment transaction 2769.","time":"2014-01-02T06:20:11.895Z","v":0}
```

After I delete these files I found them again in a day with such terrible size.

How to disable this logging on server? 
I think this is because of [pivotal plugin for newrelic redis](http://newrelic.com/plugins/pivotal/124).
Or the only way is to turn off this plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to find out about configuration options including logging level is to check with the publisher of the plugin.

In this case it appears that verbose logging is enabled by default. You can turn down the logging by placing a `#` before `verbose: 1` in the configuration file `config/newrelic_plugin.yml`.

Additionally you should consider running a log management application such as `logrotate` on your server to prevent file growth of this nature.

- [Logrotate man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)
- [Logrotate examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/)

Answer (score 3):

There's an option to [limit the log size](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/configuration/java-agent-configuration-config-file#Logging-Configuration) by changing
 newrelic.yml:

```
 log_limit_in_kbytes: <put here limit in KB>
```

Notice the comment: # The log_file_count must be set greater than 1.

You must also limit the file count:

```
 log_file_count: <2 or more>
```